# Unable to call Remote EJB from a different wildfly instance secured with keycloak

Tags: java, security, ejb-3.0, java-ee-7, keycloak

I am facing an issue while calling remote EJBs deployed on another Wildfly instance running on same machine. I have followed [this](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+server+instance) link to setup EJB invocations. I have 2 applications (both secured with keycloak) say my-caller.ear and my-callee.ear deployed on separate server instances. The structure is as follows:

```
**my-caller-app.ear**
|
|-----lib
|-----META-INF
        |-----jboss-ejb-client.xml
        |-----jboss-app.xml
        |-----application.xml       
|-----my-web.war
        |------ WEB-INF
                |----- beans.xml
                |----- jboss-web.xml [<security-domain>keycloak</security-domain>]
                |----- keycloak.json
                |----- web.xml
|---- my-ejb.jar
        |---- <org.myapp.ejb.*> // EJB classes
        |---- META-INF
                |-----jboss-ejb3.xml [<s:security-domain>keycloak</s:security-domain>]
                |-----persistence.xml


**my-callee-app.ear**
|
|-----lib
|-----META-INF
        |-----jboss-app.xml
        |-----application.xml       
|-----my-web2.war
        |------ WEB-INF
                |----- beans.xml
                |----- jboss-web.xml [<security-domain>keycloak</security-domain>]
                |----- keycloak.json
                |----- web.xml
|---- my-ejb2.jar
        |---- <org.myapp.ejb.*> // EJB classes
        |---- META-INF
                |-----jboss-ejb3.xml [<s:security-domain>keycloak</s:security-domain>]
                |-----persistence.xml
```

I have injected remote interface of my CalleeBean as follows:

```
@Resource(lookup="ejb:my-callee-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/my-ejb2/CalleeBean!com.business.CalleeBeanRemote")
    CalleeBeanRemote calleeService;
```

My standalone.xml configuration for keycloak is as follows (both servers). Also, **default-security-domain** is set to **keycloak** :

```
<default-security-domain value="keycloak"/>
......
......

<security-domain name="keycloak">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="org.keycloak.adapters.jboss.KeycloakLoginModule" flag="required"/>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

Whenever I try to call any method on my remote EJB it throws following exception on both server instances:

> javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: WFLYSEC0027: Invalid User

I enabled trace logging on my remote server (callee server), which shows as follows:

> 2017-07-15 19:54:23,867 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-47)
>   PBOX00200: Begin isValid, principal: ejb, cache entry: null 2017-07-15
>   19:54:23,868 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-47) PBOX00209:
>   defaultLogin, principal: ejb 2017-07-15 19:54:23,868 TRACE
>   [org.jboss.security] (default task-47) PBOX00221: Begin
>   getAppConfigurationEntry(keycloak), size: 6 2017-07-15 19:54:23,868
>   TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-47) PBOX00224: End
>   getAppConfigurationEntry(keycloak), AuthInfo: AppConfigurationEntry[]:
>   [0] LoginModule Class: org.keycloak.adapters.jboss.KeycloakLoginModule
>   ControlFlag: LoginModuleControlFlag: required Options:
>
> 2017-07-15 19:54:23,868 DEBUG [org.jboss.security] (default task-47)
>   PBOX00206: Login failure: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException:
>   unable to find LoginModule class:
>   org.keycloak.adapters.jboss.KeycloakLoginModule from [Module
>   "deployment.my-callee-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.my-ejb2.jar:main" from
>   Service Module Loader]    at
>   javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:794)
>     at
>   javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)
>     at
>   javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)
>     at
>   javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
>     at
>   javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
>     at
>   org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.defaultLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:406)
>     at
>   org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.proceedWithJaasLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:345)
>     at
>   org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.authenticate(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:333)
>     at
>   org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.isValid(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:146)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.security.service.SimpleSecurityManager.authenticate(SimpleSecurityManager.java:406)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.security.service.SimpleSecurityManager.authenticate(SimpleSecurityManager.java:367)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor$1.run(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:55)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor$1.run(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:49)

Surprisingly, when I deploy my both applications on same server, it runs perfectly fine.
I am sure this is some security issue on the remote server, and not the remoting issue. I think keycloak has secured my web-tier and not the EJBs (not sure). I am stuck in this issue for quite some time now.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you install the keycloak adapter on the other server as well?

Comment: @Maddin, I copied my wildfly directory to create another server. Keycloak adapter was there in first server, so I assume that other server would have it too..   Thanks.